# Python: How to Loop thoough every XML node and print values based on list

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

For Validation Purposes: How can I search thorough a whole XML node by node(even children) as below:

**XML File:**

```
<Summary>
<Hardware_Info>
    <HardwareType>FlashDrive</HardwareType>
    <ManufacturerDetail>
            <ManufacturerCompany>Company1</ManufacturerCompany>
            <ManufacturerDate>2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00</ManufacturerDate>
            <ModelCode>4BR6282</ModelCode>
    </ManufacturerDetail>
    <ActivationDate>2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00</ActivationDate>
</Hardware_Info>
<DeviceConnectionInfo>
    <Device>
        <Index>0</Index>
        <Name>Laptop1</Name>
        <Status>Installed</Status>
    </Device>
    <Device>
        <Index>1</Index>
        <Name>Laptop2</Name>
        <Status>Installed</Status>
    </Device>
</DeviceConnectionInfo>
</Summary>
```

and search for the values based on matching columns of a particular Table. For the sake of an example the table is as is:

**TABLE:**

```
HardwareType    ManufacturerCompany    ManufacturerDate             ActivationDate              Device.Index        Name
FlashDrive      Company1               2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   0                   Laptop1
FlashDrive      Company2               2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   1                   Laptop2
```

In this case I would have a column list of:

```
HardwareType, ManufacturerCompany, ManufacturerDate, ActivationDate, Device.Index, Name
```

For my final result I would like to print the values of the table column names along with the values of the table names found on the xml. For example similar like the original table (assuming validation is fine):

**OUTPUT RESULT :**

```
 HardwareType   ManufacturerCompany    ManufacturerDate             ActivationDate              Device.Index        Name
    FlashDrive      Company1               2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   0                   Laptop1
    FlashDrive      Company2               2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   1                   Laptop2
```

**CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION:**

For example I am able to get the list of the column names of the table, however but so far the best to my nkowledge to implement this is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("/test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

f = open('/test.csv', 'w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(f)

count = 0

head = ['ManufacturerCompany','ManufacturerDate',...]

csvwriter.writerow(head)

for time in root.findall('Summary'):
     row = []
     job_name = time.find('ManufacturerDetail').find('ManufacturerCompany').text
     row.append(job_name)
     job_name = time.find('ManufacturerDetail').find('ManufacturerDate').text
     row.append(job_name)
     csvwriter.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

However, this implementation does not have the loop each functionality I want for the output. Any guidance or suggestions for implementation would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files into other XML, HTML (which mostly known for), but also text files (TXT/CSV) with its `method="text"`. Specifically, walk down to the *Device* node level and bring over the ancestor items.

Python's third-party [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. However, XSLT is portable and *any* [XSLT processor](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) can run such code including Unix's (Linux/Mac) available [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file; `&#xa;` is the line break entity)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="delimiter">,</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/Summary">
    <xsl:text>HardwareType,ManufacturerCompany,ManufacturerDate,ActivationDate,Device.Index,Name&#xa;</xsl:text>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DeviceConnectionInfo"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DeviceConnectionInfo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Device"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Device">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::Summary/Hardware_Info/HardwareType, $delimiter,
                                 ancestor::Summary/Hardware_Info/ManufacturerDetail/ManufacturerCompany, $delimiter,
                                 ancestor::Summary/Hardware_Info/ManufacturerDetail/ManufacturerDate, $delimiter,
                                 ancestor::Summary/Hardware_Info/ActivationDate, $delimiter,
                                 Index, $delimiter,
                                 Name)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(with lxml)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('xslt_script.xsl')

# TRANSFORM INPUT TO STRING
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = str(transform(doc))

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Python** *(one-line command call to xsltproc)*

```
from subprocess import Popen

proc = Popen(['xsltproc -o output.csv xslt_script.xsl input.xml'], 
             shell=True, cwd='/path/to/working/directory')
```

**Output**

```
# HardwareType  ManufacturerCompany ManufacturerDate    ActivationDate  Device.Index    Name
# FlashDrive    Company1    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   0   Laptop1
# FlashDrive    Company1    2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   2017-07-20T12:26:04-04:00   1   Laptop2
```

Comment: @Pairfait, Thanks for your input, I will give it a try shortly!

Comment: @Techno04335 ... how did the trial go?

Comment: @Pairfait , I would like to clarify my understanding, based on the Column list I have, am I inputting that within the XLST file? In which this process prints/outputs the element values based on column names?

Comment: No column list is needed. You list headers in XSLT script, see `<xsl:text>...</xsl:text>` and then the other template runs XPath searches to find those needed values.

Comment: @Pairfait, I got the suggestion to work! Thanks for your assistance! I would like like your input on automating the XSLT File based on what the values I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: You can pass parameters to XSLT from Python. Consider asking a new question.